# JS Password Form Check

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been playing with this and for some reason cannot get the desired behavior. The code below has been altered and rearranged several times but requires me to click `submit` more than once and it only displays the first validity message even when the conditions are not met.

```js
function check() {
  input1 = document.getElementById('old_pass')
  input2 = document.getElementById('new_pass')
  input3 = document.getElementById('new_passV')

  if (input2.value !== input1.value && input3.value === input2.value) {
    $('#pass_form').submit();
  } else if (input2.value === input1.value) {
    input2.setCustomValidity('Your new password cannot match your old password.');
  } else if (input3.value !== input2.value) {
    input3.setCustomValidity('New password must be matching.');
  } else {
    input2.setCustomValidity('');
    input3.setCustomValidity('');
    return true;
  }
};
```

```html
<form id="pass_form" action="./php/pass-conn.php" method="POST">
  <br>
  Enter Current Password:
  <br>
  <input type="password" name="old_pass" id="old_pass" title="Password must contain at least eight characters" autofocus="autofocus">
  <br><br><br>
  Enter New Password:
  <br>
  <input type="password" name="new_pass" id="new_pass" pattern=".{8,}" title="Password must contain at least eight characters">
  <br><br>
  Confirm New Password:
  <br>
  <input type="password" name="new_passV" id="new_passV" pattern=".{8,}" title="Password must contain at least eight characters">
  <br><br>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="showpass" onclick="showpass()">
    <u>Show/Hide</u>
  </a>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" onclick="check()">
</form>
```

The desired behavior is to have a user click `submit` once and if either the old password is identical to the new one or if the new password do not match, throw a message. Otherwise, submit the form.

Comment: one thing is, you need to use `<input type="submit" onclick="return check()">` and another thing is, you need to use `return false;` everywhere inside the conditions in check function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the solution that seems to work properly.

```js
function check(){
  input1 = document.getElementById('old_pass')
  input2 = document.getElementById('new_pass')
  input3 = document.getElementById('new_passV')
  input2.setCustomValidity('');
  input3.setCustomValidity('');
  if(input2.value !== input1.value && input3.value === input2.value){
    return true;
  }else if(input2.value === input1.value){
    input2.setCustomValidity('Your new password cannot match your old password.');
    return false;
  }else if(input3.value !== input2.value){
    input3.setCustomValidity('New password must be matching.');
    return false;
  }
};
```

```html
<form id="pass_form" method="POST"><br>
  Enter Current Password: <br><input type="password" name="old_pass" id="old_pass" title="Password must contain at least eight characters" autofocus="autofocus"><br><br><br>
  Enter New Password: <br><input type="password" name="new_pass" id="new_pass" pattern=".{8,}" title="Password must contain at least eight characters"><br><br>
  Confirm New Password: <br><input type="password" name="new_passV" id="new_passV" pattern=".{8,}" title="Password must contain at least eight characters"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" onclick="check()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing is, you need to use `<input type="submit" onclick="return check()">` and another thing is, you need to use `return false;` everywhere inside the conditions in check function, if it has to be not sent. And if everything is correct, just `return true` and then the form will be submitted.

```js
function check() {
 input1 = document.getElementById('old_pass');
 input2 = document.getElementById('new_pass');
 input3 = document.getElementById('new_passV');
 
 if (input2.value !== input1.value && input3.value === input2.value) {
  return true;
 }
 else if (input2.value === input1.value) {
  input2.setCustomValidity('Your new password cannot match your old password.');
  return false;
 }
 else if (input3.value !== input2.value) {
  input3.setCustomValidity('New password must be matching.');
  return false;
 }
}
```

```html
<form id="pass_form" action="./php/pass-conn.php" method="POST"><br>
 Enter Current Password: <br><input type="password" name="old_pass" id="old_pass" title="Password must contain at least eight characters" autofocus="autofocus"><br><br><br>
 Enter New Password: <br><input type="password" name="new_pass" id="new_pass" pattern=".{8,}" title="Password must contain at least eight characters"><br><br>
 Confirm New Password: <br><input type="password" name="new_passV" id="new_passV" pattern=".{8,}" title="Password must contain at least eight characters"><br><br>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="showpass" onclick="showpass()"><u>Show/Hide</u></a><br><br>
 <input type="submit" onclick="return check()">
</form>
```

Comment: I turned this into a snippet but it does not seem to run as expected (I dont think I altered any of it). I am using chrome currently.

Comment: I formatted the code for better readability and its working fine. In your solution you are missing `return check()`, it should be instead just `check()`.